# PCA on part of dataset

Tags: categorical-data, pca, continuous-data, mixed-type-data

I have read numerous questions/answers on this site and others debating the use of PCA and other dimensionality reduction techniques on mixed data (containing both continuous and categorical variables). I have seen no reference to the idea of idea performing PCA on only the continuous variables and holding out the categorical ones.

What are the ramifications of this approach? Specifically,  I am thinking of performing PCA on only the continuous variables, and then using the computed components and held-out categorical variables to build a model.

In my situation, I am more concerned with final model performance than understanding the relationship, though re-computing the original continuous variables from the loadings would not be overly difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying PCA on only the continuous variables is the simples approach if you have mixed data. If you do not care about a seperate set of categorical variables that this is the approach for you.

However, there are a few cases when this approach is not sufficient:

- The majority of the dataset is categorical and only reducing the dimension of the continuous variables is not enough.
- You want to have an similar scale for all of the variables, including the categorical ones.
- Subsequent steps require continuous data and you want to use dimension reduction to achieve this
- The categorical variables contain a lot of duplicate information, excluding them from the dimension reduction might hurt modelling performance.

Comment: Is there any literature you can point me to that supports this answer?

Comment: Not that I know of